# Fluent min length validation incorrect when using chinese character

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have the following fluent validator, which works fine when the characters are in english but fails when charcaters are in chinese.

How can i instruct it that characters are unicode and it should validate it accordingly.

```
RuleFor(x => x.FirstName)
    .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify FirstName")
    .MaximumLength(500).MinimumLength(3);
```

Comment: can you please use WithMessage("your message"); for MaximumLength and MinimumLength and test it?

Comment: This is an interesting problem. According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/), the `Length` property of a string returns the number of `char` objects inside the string, **not the number of unicode characters**. I'm willing to bet the FluentValidation rule uses `String.Length` by default. Is there an overload of `MaximumLength` that allows you to pass the string encoding?